# How to create a mail server locally that can receive mail from Gmail?

Tags: smtp, mail-server

I want to host a local mail server, which can receive mail from gmail or other well known mail provider. Which mail server software should I use ? Free if possible. How do I configure it ?

Also can you explain how it work ? I know smtp server need authentication (username/password) to send email in same server, but how does it work with different smtp server ? They can't have an account in each other server right ?

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question is a bit too open-ended. Have a look at https://mailinabox.email/, for example.

There are two separate protocols: "SMTP for Submission" and "SMTP for Relay". The first is used by mail clients to submit messages to the user's outgoing mail server. It usually requires authentication with username and password. The latter is used by outgoing mail servers to relay messages to the incoming mail server of each recipient. Historically, this hasn't been authenticated at all, which is why you can spoof the sender address so easily. Newer standards (namely SPF, DKIM, and DMARC) introduced domain authentication, which addresses this problem.